# how to call method in every one minute using java?

Tags: java, timer

I want to call method in every 1 min in Java.  Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [`TimerTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html?is-external=true) which you can schedule for repeated execution via [`Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).

Alternatively use a [quartz trigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html) if you want something a bit more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2):

Still cannot see [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) among the variants.

Answer (score -3):

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    yourMethod();
}
```

Something as simple as this, or if you need accurate precision, you've to use [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: Avoid `Thread.sleep()`.  This is what `Timer` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` or even a full-up scheduling framework is for.  Introducing `sleep()` into code just complicates things, and it should not be relied upon for timing.

Answer (score -3):

one simple way of doing it is

```
while (...) { Thread.sleep(60000); //do something }
```

Comment: Avoid `Thread.sleep()`.  This is what `Timer` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` or even a full-up scheduling framework is for.  Introducing `sleep()` into code just complicates things, and it should not be relied upon for timing.

Comment: @andersoj agreed, but wanted to show the OP that it is one of the ways, although it's pretty crappy.